# How to call F# type extensions (static member functions) from C#

Tags: c#, f#

FSharp code is structured as following (I'm not in control of the source).

```
namespace FS

[<AbstractClass; Sealed>]
type TestType() = 
    static member IrrelevantFunction() = 
        0

[<AutoOpen>]
module Extensions = 
    type TestType with
        //How do we call this from C#
        static member NeedToCallThis() = 
            0

module Caller = 
    let CallIt() = 
        //F# can call it
        TestType.NeedToCallThis()
```

C# calling code is as follows

```
public void Caller()
{
    TestType.IrrelevantFunction();

    //We want to call this
    //TestType.NeedToCallThis();

    //Metadata:

    //namespace FS
    //{
    //    [Microsoft.FSharp.Core.AutoOpenAttribute]
    //    [Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationMappingAttribute]
    //    public static class Extensions
    //    {
    //        public static int TestType.NeedToCallThis.Static();
    //    }
    //}

    //None of these compile
    //TestType.NeedToCallThis();
    //Extensions.TestType.NeedToCallThis.Static();
    //Extensions.TestType.NeedToCallThis();
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a reflector to figure out what the full name of the method is? ILSpy should work fine :)

Comment: @Luaan Even knowing the full name isn't enough - C# can't use it directly. The question itself actually *shows* the full name in the comments.

Comment: @ReedCopsey That's a useful piece of information that will save the OP a lot of time, of course :P It's a bit of a shame that C# doesn't allow quoted identifiers... for interop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe the method can be called directly from C# without using reflection, as the compiled method name is not a valid method name in C#.

Using reflection, you can call it via:

```
var result = typeof(FS.Extensions).GetMethod("TestType.NeedToCallThis.Static").Invoke(null,null);
```

Comment: Ug.  I was afraid this would be the case.  It's really unfortunate as the said api is a PCL FSharp.Core reflection api.  (FSharpValue.GetUnionFields)

Comment: @KennethIto Yeah - they're really only intended to be used from F#.  You can use `[<Extension>]` to make extension methods that are C# consumable, but that one wasn't really ever intended for those purposes.

Comment: Ahh, I think I would care a lot less about not being able to work with f# reflection from c# if there were f# shared projects.  Hopefully something comes of this https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/6429294-add-support-for-universal-apps-shared-projects

Comment: @KennethIto Well, you can always make your own interop library in F# to provide a C#-pretty interface. You can even inline it in your C# assembly (as another assembly module), though there's no IDE support for that.